# Legend in Form works correctly in Safari but not in Mozilla

Tags: css, forms

The legend in my form is actually not fitting in the Mozilla browser while it is in safari browser, please how can i fix it, below  is the mark up language, and the related css is also below.and i have also attached the images as well.thanks

```
  <div>
<form action='relogin.php' method='post' class='rl'>
<fieldset>
<legend>Login</legend>
    <div>
    <label for='username' class='fixedwidth'>Username</label>
    <input type='text' name='username' id='username'/>
    </div>

    <div>
    <label for='password' class='fixedwidth'>Password</label>
    <input type='password' name='password' id='password'/>
    </div>
<div class='buttonarea'>
    <input type='submit' value='Log in'/>
    </div>
<p>
<a href='reregister.php'>Register </a>
</p>
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
```

css

```
form.rl,form.slistbar{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    margin-top:-15px;
    line-height:150%;

}

form.rl,form.slistbar label {
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size: small;
}

form.rl,form.slistbar label.fixedwidth{
    display:block;
    width: 240px;

}

form.rl,form.slistbar .buttonarea input{
colour: white;
font-weight; bold;
padding: 5px;
border: 1px solid white;
}

form.rl,form.slistbar fieldset{
border:2px solid navy;
padding:10px;
width: 150px;
margin-top:30px;
}

form.rl,form.slistbar legend{
font-weight:bold;
font-size: small;
colour: navy;
}
```

safari 
[image: safari image]

[image: mozilla]

Comment: Have you tried setting the width of your text fields?

Comment: @SaladinAkara  do you mean like form.rl,form.slistbar label.fixedwidth{
 display:block;
 width: 240px;

Answer (score 1):

The [grouping operator `,`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#grouping) doesn't work like this. A comma `,` will separate several [selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors), each of them has to be valid and fully defined. ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/andVv/))

So instead of

```
form.rl,form.slistbar label {
    /* ... */
}
```

you actually want

```
form.rl label, form.slistbar label {
    /* ... */
}
```

since you want to affect `form.r1 label` and `form.slistbar label`, not `form.r1` and `form.slistbar label`.
Also note that it's [`color:`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/colors.html#colors) and not `colour`, as the W3C is creating standards/recommendations in *American English*.

Comment: it would be really nice if languages worked in both american and british english :P

Comment: @Geekfish: English isn't my first language and I learned British English in school at the same time I started using CSS, so it's okay. Whenever I ask myself "`colour` or `color`" I just think "choose the shorter one, programmers are lazy" and I tend to be right :D. (OT: It would be horrible if major programming languages were written in some kind of esoteric language. Or mirror lanugage: `ftnirp("!dlroW olleH");`)

Answer (score 1):

Where is `.slistbar` in your markup? are the elements contained in `.slistbar?`

I'm not 100% sure about why it works on safari but `form.rl, form.slistbar fieldset` does not apply the style to `fieldset` in both `form.rl` and `form.slistbar`, it applies it to `form.rl` (as in the form element itself) and `fieldset` elements within `form.slistbar`.

You probably want to do something like:

`form.rl fieldset, form.slistbar fieldset { ...`
and similar for the rest of your styles.

Comment: .slistbar is another form on another page

Comment: then the problem is your selectors, as with @Zeta's answer below, the way you have used the comma your styles do not apply in the elements within `form.rl` but on `form.rl` itself.